# Модель-представление. Создание иерархической модели

Tags: c++, qt, модель-данных

Пытаюсь создать свою модель для `std::map<Reader, std::list<Book>` (в `Reader` находятся два `string`, а список представляет собой список из (максимум пяти) элементов, состоящих также из двух `string`). При этом хочу сделать так, чтобы на верху иерархии были объекты типа `Reader`, а внизу - объекты типа `Books`. Извините, если формулировки не совсем понятные. Вообщем вот мой код:

```
ModelReader::ModelReader(const Journal &journal, ::QObject *parent)
    : ::QAbstractTableModel{parent}, journal_{journal} {}

::QVariant ModelReader::data(const ::QModelIndex &index, int Role) const {
  if (!index.isValid() || index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= journal_.size() ||
      index.column() < 0 || index.column() >= 3) {
    return ::QVariant{};
  }
  auto iter = journal_.begin();
  std::advance(iter, index.row());
  if (Role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
    switch (index.column()) {
    case 0:
      return ::QString{iter->first.get_name().c_str()};
    case 1:
      return ::QString{iter->first.get_surname().c_str()};
    case 2:
      return ::QString::number(iter->second.size());
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
  return ::QVariant{};
}

int ModelReader::rowCount(const ::QModelIndex &parent) const {
  if (parent.isValid()) {
      auto iter = journal_.begin();
      std::advance(iter, parent.row());
      return iter->second.size();
  }
  return journal_.size();
}

int ModelReader::columnCount(const ::QModelIndex &parent) const {
  if (parent.isValid()) {
    return 2;
  }
  return 3;
}

::QVariant ModelReader::headerData(int nSection, Qt::Orientation orientation,
                                   int Role) const {
  if (Role != Qt::DisplayRole) {
    return ::QVariant{};
  }
  if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
    switch (nSection) {
    case 0:
      return ::QString{"Name"};
    case 1:
      return ::QString{"Surname"};
    case 2:
      return ::QString{"Capasity"};
    default:
      return ::QVariant{};
    }
  } else {
    return ::QString::number(nSection);
  }
}

Qt::ItemFlags ModelReader::flags(const ::QModelIndex &index) const {
  Qt::ItemFlags flags = ::QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
  return index.isValid() ? (flags | Qt::ItemIsEnabled) : flags;
}
```

Тобишь, как видите, часть с объектами `Reader` я сделал, но вот не понимаю как мне запихнуть сюда `Book` так, чтобы они были подчинены объектам `Reader`.

PS прошу не обращать внимание на магические цифры и т.п. - это тестовая модель.

Comment: Или я не понял задачу, или я не понимаю что такое иерархия... Есть список читателей, с каждым читателем связан список книг, что и представлено ассоциативным массивом. Где здесь иерархия вообще? Это независимые объекты - отношение между ними есть, а иерархии нету.

Comment: @freim иерархия - это порядок подчиненности. Сдесь подчиненным объектом выступает `std::list<Book>`.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, и каким образом список книг будет подчиняться  (использовать) имена  людей? Я тоже не понел задачу. Не понел также зачем нужны определения методов, которые вы представили.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan теперь я что-то не понял: что вы имеете ввиду под "подчиняться (использовать) имена людей"? Он и не должен никак их использовать. Представте это как иерархию файлов: в папке с именем `Reader` лежат объекты `Book`  - как `Book` будут использовать `Reader`? Что касается методов - что конкретно вам не понятно?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, мне кажется, вы путаете иерархию и отношения. Штаны не являются частью иерархии человека, он их просто носит. Точно также и с книгами - книга на моей полке не является частью моей иерархии и не является моим подчиненным объектом. Она просто стоит у меня на полке. Не усложняйте простые вещи.

Comment: @freim а с каких пор иерархия - это не отношение? Я же писал: это что-то вроде иерархии файловой системы: представте, что `Reader` - это папка, а `Book` - файл в этой папке

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, иерархия - это, безусловно, отношение, но не всякое отношение можно назвать иерархией. Пример с файловой системой тут не подходит - каталоги файловой системы действительно являются иерархией, но файлы, в них содержащиеся - нет. Независимые объекты не составляют иерархию, даже если связаны неким отношением. Вы, конечно, можете и тут вставить какую-то иерарархическую связь, но это будет нагромождением сложностей на пустом месте. Ваш ассоциативный массив полностью описывает систему, больше там ничего не нужно.

Comment: @freim вмысле мне ничего больше не нужно? Мне нужна МОДЕЛЬ!!! Да, ассоциативный массив полностью описывает систему, но как же представление? В данном случае в представлении я имею только `Reader`ов, но не `Book`и - в этом то и вопрос: как сюда и их включить?

Comment: @freim,  обьекты и даже функции тоже  могут создать иерархию. Но дело не в этом, тут просто  вопрос сформулирован немного не понятно, но в принципе, если человек заранее извеняется  за плохую формулировку, то нужно стараться понять суть вопроса...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если уж совсем упростить: мне просто нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `Reader` выпадал список из `Book` которые храняться в списке ассоциируемом с `Reader`. Тобишь как в файловой системе, когда жмешь на папку и выпадает список файлов содержащихся в ней.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, _мне просто нужно, чтобы при нажатии на Reader выпадал список из Book которые храняться в списке ассоциируемом с Reader_ - и что мешает вам это сделать? Представление в стиле файловой системы вполне можно использовать, только упрощенное, без дерева (иерархии нет поскольку все читатели равноправны).

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, _обьекты и даже функции тоже могут создать иерархию_ - я с этим и не спорил. Я говорил, что **независимые** объекты не составляют иерархию.

Comment: @freim то что я не знаю как включить это в модель - вот что мешает. Об этом вообще-то и вопрос.

Comment: Зачем представление включать в модель? Смысл этой концепции как раз в том, чтобы наоборот, отделить представление от модели. Представление отдельно, а модель просто извещает его об изменениях - через механизм событий, обратных вызовов, или еще как-то.

Comment: @freim ну так может раскажете, как тогда какой-нибудь `QTreeView` должен отобразить данные, которые не включены в модель?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80860/discussion-between-freim-and-andrej-levkovitch).